# Flexslider - Load specific slide from huge group

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, flexslider

I'm working on a slider to browse all available units in a condo building.  This is for a touchscreen in the building so it made sense to use flexslider since it's touch friendly and easy to set up.  [Here's the working example](http://twelvetwelve.com/residences/unit-all.php)...       Now the hard part...   there are close to 300 slides, and the unit #s don't match the slide #s.  Slide 5 might be unit 412.  Does anyone have a recommendation on how to link to a specific slide from a separate page other than just keeping a huge list of variables assigning each unit # to a slide in the array?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: What exactly do you want? Just loading a specific slide from a different page without knowing what unit # it is. Or, a way to smartly map the slide #s with unit #s?

Comment: Smartly map unit #s to slide #s.  So if someone is looking a layout of the whole building and they click on unit 1503, it would load the floorplan slider and jump directly to that slide, whatever it might be.